# Why this pojo program "readline" always return null?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("day.txt"));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("day.txt"));
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
}
```

The day.txt I have wrote some words before execute. If I change System.out.println with Writer, it will not be null. why?

Comment: Why did you create a writer for the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the writer instance after printing out to console. When the writer is initialized, the file is in use so you can't read it.

Comment: Thx bro, I try it(Writer). It really create a file.

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting the same file when you do `new FileWriter("day.txt");`

change your code to

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("day.txt"));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("day-new.txt"));
System.out.println(reader.readLine());
```

Comment: The writer can also be instantiated with `new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("day.txt", true))`, as an alternative (`append = true`)